# Получить комментарии к посту в канале telegram на pyrogram

Tags: telegram-bot, pyrogram

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно в телеграмм канале получить комменатрии к необходимым мне постам на pyrogram (при необходимости, можно и не pyrogram). Не смог сам найти ничего путного, возможно ли это вообще сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример основных функций, которые могут быть нужны при взаемодействии с коментариями:

```
@app.on_message(filters.channel)
async def handle_channel_post(client, message):
    # Количество коментов
    comments_count = await app.get_discussion_replies_count(message.chat.id, message.id)

    # Пройтись по коментам
    async for message in app.get_discussion_replies(chat_id, message_id):
        print(message)

    # Прокоментировать пост
    discussion_message = await app.get_discussion_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
    await discussion_message.reply("Great post! :D")
```

Ссылка на все это в документации:

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_discussion_replies_count

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_discussion_replies

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_discussion_message

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]